# hangman in vb trying to display correct leters and wrong ones with "*"

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need help trying to create a hang man game. I somehow cant display correct letters properly.I'm using a intGuessed array and a word array. compare the two and display the correct letters and "*" for incorrect letters.

code:

```
    For I As Integer = 0 To 9
        Console.WriteLine(“Enter a letter please: ”)
        strInput = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine()
        If [Char].TryParse(strInput, charInput) Then
            For G As Integer = 0 To word.Length - 1
                Select Case strInput
                    Case word(G)
                        ReDim Preserve aryGuessed(G + 1)
                        If Not aryGuessed.Contains(charInput) Then
                            aryGuessed(intGuessed) = charInput
                            intGuessed += 1
                        End If
                        For A As Integer = 0 To aryGuessed.Length - 1
                            For B As Integer = 0 To word.Length - 1
                                If aryGuessed(A) = word(B) Then
                                    Console.Write(word(B))
                                End If
                            Next
                        Next
                        If G >= word.Length Then
                            Console.Write("correct")
                        End If
                    Case Else
                        Console.Write("*")
                        If G >= word.Length Then
                            bolwrong = True
                        End If
                End Select
                Console.WriteLine()
            Next
        End If
        If bolwrong = True Then
            intScore += 1
            Console.WriteLine("incorrect")
            Console.WriteLine("your score is now " + intScore.ToString())
            Console.ReadLine()
            bolwrong = False
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: You have a significant wad of code there.  One would hope that you have a clear idea of what it is supposed to. I don't just mean the end result but also the steps to get there.  have you actually debugged that code, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through it line by line? If not, you need to do that.  You always need to do that before posting here. If you have then you know exactly where what it actually does differs from your expectation, so you can tell us where and how. If it doesn't differ from your expectation then your expectations are wrong, so you need to reevaluate those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than looping lots, I would suggest the following code. I've shuffled things around a bit to make more sense, but the main changes are that I've created a string with the same number of '*' as the original word, and replaced a chunk of code with something simpler and more efficient.

ultimately most of your `For .. Select Case .. End Case .. Next` block can be replaced with ..

```
For G As Integer = 0 To word.Length - 1
    If word(G) = charInput Then
        guessedWord = guessedWord.Remove(G, 1).Insert(G, strInput)
        boolWrong = False
    End If
Next
```

And the guess/completion checking logic can be move toward the end of the outer loop.

This is what your final code would look like ..

```
Dim guessedWord As New String("*"c, word.Length)
For I As Integer = 0 To 9
    Console.WriteLine(“Enter a letter please: ”)
    strInput = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()
    boolWrong = True
    If Char.TryParse(strInput, charInput) Then
        aryGuessed(I) = strInput
        For G As Integer = 0 To word.Length - 1
            If word(G) = charInput Then
                guessedWord = guessedWord.Remove(G, 1).Insert(G, strInput)
                boolWrong = False
            End If
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine(guessedWord)
        ReDim Preserve aryGuessed(aryGuessed.Count)
    End If
    If guessedWord = word Then
        Console.Write("Correct!")
        Exit For
    End If
    If boolWrong = True Then
        intScore += 1
        Console.WriteLine("incorrect")
        Console.WriteLine("your score is now " + intScore.ToString())
    End If
Next
```

Incidentally, this line

```
guessedWord = guessedWord.Remove(G, 1).Insert(G, strInput)
```

is a rather neat way of accomplishing the removal of a character and inserting a character all on one line

Its the same as writing

```
guessedWord = guessedWord.Remove(G, 1)
guessedWord = guessedWord.Insert(G, strInput)
```